# Как перейти на страницу переменной $to?

Tags: javascript, php, html, php7, php5

```
<?php
$to = substr(md5(time()), 0, 8) .'.php'; // 8 - количество символов
$word = "<?php echo 123; ?>";
  file_put_contents($to, $word);

// Помещаем данные в текстовый файл 
$fd = fopen($filename, "a"); 
  if(!$fd) exit("Ошибка при открытии файла данных"); 
$str = $_POST['name']."::". 
    $_POST['pass']."::". 
    $_POST['email']."::". 
    $to."\r\n"; 
    fwrite($fd,$str); 
    fclose($fd); 
// Осуществляем перезагрузку страницы, 
// чтобы сбросить POST-данные 
echo "<HTML><HEAD> 
<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL='$to'>
        </HEAD></HTML>"; 
?>
```

Исправьте, пожалуйста, код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 window.location = 'google.com'
```

в твоем случае $to